# Rails validate if radiobutton virtual attrib value is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

My model now is such:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :**** :phone_number, :receiver, :shipping_id, :street, :totalcost, :user_id, :zip, :use_user_data
  attr_accessor :use_user_data
  validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}
  validates :zip, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:zip_not_chosen)}
  validates :street, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:street__not_chosen)}
  validates :building, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:building_not_chosen)}
  validates :phone_number, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:phone_number_not_chosen)}
  validates :receiver, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:receiver_not_chosen)}
end
```

As you can see i set in model some field which is non-db field (use_user_data)...

But how to do, if :use_user_data is false, good and right validate, but when true didn't validate?

Here as i think to do:

```
  if !:use_user_data
    validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}
    validates :zip, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:zip_not_chosen)}
    validates :street, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:street__not_chosen)}
    validates :building, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:building_not_chosen)}
    validates :phone_number, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:phone_number_not_chosen)}
    valida
```

form

```
= form_for @order do |f|
  %div
    = f.label :use_user_data , "Использовать данные вашего профиля*: "
    = label :use_user_data , "Да"
    = f.radio_button :use_user_data, true, :required => true, :id => "use_user_data", :checked => true
    = label :use_user_data , "Нет"
    = f.radio_button :use_user_data, false, :required => true, :id => "dont_use_user_data"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional validation with options `:if` or `:unless`. Example:

```
validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}, :unless => :use_user_data
```

Look at the [Rails Guide on Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation) for other sytntaxes, the last one might be the most suitable in your case:

```
with_options :unless => :use_user_data do |order|
  order.validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}
  order.validates :zip, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:zip_not_chosen)}
  order.validates :street, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:street__not_chosen)}
  # ...
end
```

Comment: first is no working... second too... i didn't get them when i need

Comment: if i do with if i get undefined method `use_user_data?'

Comment: so, why you are not answering?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358126/validate-fields-only-if-virt-attribute-is-false#comment19963831_14358126  here i get right answer