# Validate fields only if virt_attribute is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I have such model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :**** :phone_number, :receiver, :shipping_id, :street, :totalcost, :user_id, :zip, :use_user_data
  attr_accessor :use_user_data
  validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}
  validates :zip, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:zip_not_chosen)}
  validates :street, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:street__not_chosen)}
  validates :building, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:building_not_chosen)}
  validates :phone_number, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:phone_number_not_chosen)}
  validates :receiver, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:receiver_not_chosen)}
end
```

As you can see i set in model some field which is non-db field (use_user_data) - virtual attribute...

But how to do, if :use_user_data is false, good and right validate, but when true didn't validate?

i try so:

```
validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}, :unless => :use_user_data
```

and so

```
with_options :unless => :use_user_data do |order|
    order.validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}
  end
```

but it doesn't help me... Why?

Also my form:

```
= form_for @order do |f|
  %div
    = f.label :use_user_data , "Использовать данные вашего профиля*: "
    = label :use_user_data , "Да"
    = f.radio_button :use_user_data, true, :required => true, :id => "use_user_data", :checked => true
    = label :use_user_data , "Нет"
    = f.radio_button :use_user_data, false, :required => true, :id => "dont_use_user_data"
```

Also when i write

```
validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}, :if => :use_user_data
```

i get validation messages... But how to do only if false? And why my solution didn't work?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can clean up your many `:message` parameters using *implict* lookups: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2859275/23368

Comment: @DanielRikowski and how to change.... didn't unserstand, delete message? and?

Comment: Just set up your locale files the way described in the Rails I18n guide at "Error Message Scopes" (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes) and Rails will automatically use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form passes "true" or "false" string to the object, not boolean `true` or `false`. Since it's a virtual attribute, no typecasting performed. In Ruby, both "true" and "false" are `true`, so you need to use something to typecast the value

```
with_options :unless => Proc.new{ |a| a.use_user_data == 'true' } do |order|
  order.validates ...
end
```

Or

```
with_options :unless => :use_user_data? do |order|
  order.validates ...
end

def use_user_data?
  use_user_data == 'true'
end
```

Comment: maybe do |order|
  order.validates ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `:if` or `:unless` conditions in a lambda or [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html).

```
validates ..., :if => Proc.new { |a| a.use_user_data === false }
```

This causes the check against `:use_user_data` to not be evaluated until the above `validates` line is executed during validation *(the `Proc` is passed as the value to the `:if` or `:unless` option to be evaluated by Rails)*. The `Proc` will receive the current model attributes as an argument, allowing you to check those attributes *(in this case, `:use_user_data` being `false`)*.